# SimpleXML получение атрибутов

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется XML файл с таким по типу содержанием

```
<Catalogue>
    <Item>
        <ID>0</ID>
        <Name>Product name 1</Name>
        <AttributeList>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 1" Value="value 1"/>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 2" Value="value 2"/>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 3" Value="value 3"/>
        </AttributeList>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>Product name 2</Name>
        <AttributeList>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 1" Value="value 1"/>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 2" Value="value 2"/>
            <Attribute Name="Attribute name 3" Value="value 3"/>
        </AttributeList>
    </Item>
</Catalogue>
```

С помощью "SimpleXML" прошелся по всем дочерним полям "Item" но никак не смог поместить значения атрибутов в массив products();

```
<?php

$xml_product_list = simplexml_load_file('xml/katalog.xml');

function getXML($xml_product) {

    // Get products
    $products = array();
    $attributes = array();

    foreach ($xml_product->Catalogue->Item as $item) {

        foreach ($item->AttributeList as $attribute_list)

        $products[] = array(
            'id' => (string) $item->ID,
            'attributes' => $attribute_list
        );
    }

    var_dump($products);
}

echo '<pre>';
getXML($xml_product_list);
echo '</pre>';
```

Чтобы не делал, либо ошибки, либо в ячейку атрибуты заносится только значения первого тэга "Attribute", но не все остальные...
Каким образом можно занести все значения полей "Attribute" в ячейку массива "attributes" для конкретного "Item"?

Comment: Форычить каждый элемент списка `AttributeList` и помещать их в массив attributes к каждому товару))

Comment: `AttributeList->Attribute->attributes()->Name` Я как-то так обычно получаю...

Comment: вы напишите вид желаемого результата, чтобы понятно было

Comment: А ещё лучше использовать инструменты по прямому назначению. Для подобного хранения данных используется JSON. XML в данном случае некорректно использовать, так как он предназначен для разметки чего-либо, а не хранения данных по типу "ключ-значение".

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
foreach ($xml_product->Item as $item) {

    foreach ($item->AttributeList as $attributeList) {
        /** @var SimpleXMLElement $attribute */
        foreach ($attributeList as $attribute) {
            $products[] = [
                'id' => (string)$item->ID,
                'attributes' => [
                    'name' => (string)$attribute->attributes()->Name,
                    'value' => (string)$attribute->attributes()->Value,
                ],
            ];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если так, то в ячейке "attributes" - содержится массив "Attribute" и внутри его еще один массив со значениями атрибутов, но я их разбить по парам не получается...

Comment: Поправил ответ, если аттрибуты динамические можно еще один цикл.

Comment: Таким образом он разбивает один товар на несколько дубликатов в котором есть атрибут, это не совсем верно, правильно когда в одном товаре есть сразу все указанны атрибуты.  Я вот как раз, нашел способ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771960/convert-php-array-from-xml-that-contains-duplicate-elements . Но это через DOM